# Spring boot UserDetailsService Multi-User with extra fields

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-data, user-roles

I have a spring boot project that has 3 types of users (Admin, Expert, Customer) and the application is for Experts that register on site for giving services like fixing computers to Customers that are asking help in site.

I have an inheritance of different kind of `User` types as following.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "USER_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class User {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();

    // getter & setter...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Admin extends User {
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class Expert extends User {

    private Byte[] expertPhoto;
    private String password;

    // some other fields & getter & setter...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("3")
public class Customer extends User {

    private Long credit;
    private Set<CustomerOrder> orders = new HashSet<>();

    // some other fields & getter & setter...
}
```

I want to use spring boot security and implement UserDetailsService, my problem is that how to design when I have different User types (Expert, Customer, etc.)?

I want users to be able to have different roles (admin, expert, customer) with one username.

How should I design my system to solve these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Your role modal seems a bit off. It is better to have a single type of `User` and fill it with list of a new `Role` entity. The new `User` entity will look like the following:

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

// getters and setters & other fields user can have

}
```

And the `Role` entity will look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "role_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String roleName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

Then, you need to implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` interface to use as a concrete implementation of spring security class `User`on your `UserDetailsService`. Notice that this class is also called `User` and is different than the `User` class on your system.

```
public class MyUserDetail extends User {

    private String otherFieldsLikePhoto; // you can add different fields like this to keep extra information

    public MyUserDetail(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String otherFieldsLikePhoto) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.otherFieldsLikePhoto = otherFieldsLikePhoto;
    }
}
```

Then, you can create your `UserDetailsService` by implementing `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` of spring security.

What you will achieve `UserDetailsService` is to load the user in the `MyUserDetail` format we just created. It will be something like this:

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserReadService userReadService; // put your service to get user from db

    public MyUserDetailsService(UserReadService UserReadService) {
        this.userReadService = UserReadService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userReadService.getByUsername(username); // get user from db
        String otherFieldsLikePhoto = getUserPhotoOrAnythingElse(user); // get your extra fields however you want

        return new MyUserDetail(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                getAuthoritySetOfUser(user), // notice how we embed roles to UserDetail
                otherFieldsLikePhoto
        );
    }

    // this function is not necessary but useful to calculate authority set calculation on helper
    private Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthoritySetOfUser(User user) {
        Set<Role> userRoles = user.getRoles();  // get roles of user like ADMIN, EXPERT etc.
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream()
            .map(rolex -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rolex.getRoleName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
       

        return authorities;
    }

}
```